# Drag and Drop Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**UPDATE: Found this ticket about the bug http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5718. I try the position:absolute but it breaks the data on html**

I have implemented drag and drop in my app to sort data. When dragging of data it must be align with others data. But in the picture below.

[image]

Notice that, when I drag the Internet it goes on top.

It must be align with others when dragging. How to fix this? Is there a way that the data must be in the cursor, not on the top when dragging?

**Here are the codes for drag and drop:**

```
 <script>
    var addPositions = function() {
        $('.dropenv, .dropcat').each(function() {
            var position = 0;
            $(this).children().each(function() {
                $(this).data('position', position);
                position++;
            });
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        addPositions();

        $(".dropenv").sortable({
            connectWith: "tbody.env-data",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            handle: '.env-handle',
            start: function(event, ui) {
                parentID = ui.item.parent().siblings('tr').attr('id');
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                datas = new Array();
                var i = 0;

                ui.item.closest('tbody').children('tr').each(function() {
                    datas[i] = $(this).attr('id');
                    i++;
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 
                        'cat_id': parentID,
                        'env[]': datas, 
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    }, 
                    url:"/envelopes/sort/",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) { 
                        notify('', data, { autoClose: true, delay: 1000 });
                    },
                    error: function(ts) { 
                        notify('', ts.responseText, { autoClose: true, delay: 1000 });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $( ".dropcat").sortable({
            connectWith: "tbody.cat-data",
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            handle: '.cat-handle',
            update: function(){
                datas = new Array();
                var i = 0;

                $('.dropcat tr.masterList').each(function() {
                    datas[i] = $(this).attr('id');
                    i++;
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 
                        'cat[]': datas, 
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    }, 
                    url:"/envelopes/categories/sort/",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) { 
                        notify('', data, { autoClose: true, delay: 1000 });
                    },
                    error: function(ts) { 
                        notify('', ts.responseText, { autoClose: true, delay: 1000 });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to show the code you have. Very few of us are psychic enough to diagnose the problem without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: `overflow:auto`

```
<table class="simple-table responsive-table" style="overflow:auto">
```